# Lista dentro de um Dicionário

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Eu tenho um método que recebe uma lista de produtos, percorre esta lista e precisa retornar n listas de produtos separados pelo CNAE. Estou tentando retornar como um dicionario, mas ai que bate a dúvida. Se depois de adicionar um item na lista, durante a 1ª vez, na 2ª vez eu consigo adicionar mais um item na lista? 
Eu fiz da seguinte forma.

```cs
public IValidationResult GerarListas(List<TPV_PedidoItemInfo> Items, string TipoOS)
        {
            IValidationResult result = ValidationResult.Clear();
            try
            {
                using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0) }))
                {

                    List<string> osTiposItens = new List<string>();

                    Dictionary<string, List<TPV_PedidoItemInfo>> listas = new Dictionary<string, List<TPV_PedidoItemInfo>>();
                    string key = "items";

                    foreach (TPV_PedidoItemInfo item in Items)
                    {
                        TAS_ProdutoInfo Produto = uow.TAS_ProdutoRepository.FindById(item.IDProduto);
                        if (Produto == null)
                        {
                            result.Add("Produto não encontrado!");
                            return result;
                        }

                        if (item.TipoItem != "I")
                        {
                            if (Produto.CNAE != null)
                            {
                                key += Produto.CNAE;
                                if (!listas.ContainsKey(key))
                                {
                                    listas.Add(key, new List<TPV_PedidoItemInfo> { item });
                                }
                                else {
                                    listas[key].Add(item);
                                }

                                if (!osTiposItens.Contains(key))
                                {
                                    osTiposItens.Add(key);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    result.Object = new { listas};

                    scope.Complete();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result.Add(ex.Message);
                result.Object = new { ex };
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente o erro está na linha `key += Produto.CNAE;`. Ao fazer o `+=` dentro de um `foreach` a sua key não tem o valor que você espera.

Coloque a criação da key (`string key = "items";`) dentro do `foreach` e já deve ter o resultado esperado.

Outra opção seria usar somente `Produto.CNAE` como Key, fazendo `key = Produto.CNAE`.